# rendering react server-side is causing an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs

I am trying to work on node, and I'll be the first to admit it is a bit beyond me. Without a good list of tutorials, and troubleshooting being limited, I am doing my best to ask as few questions as I can, in the proper fashion. I believe I am messing up a require, but it could just be I do not fully understand renderToString. I am running node, express, and react, and eventually, I'd like to work with the MERN stack.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
import React from "react";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
```

Those are just my imports, and stuff automatically loaded by the express CLI. Just thought I'd include them in case they were relevant.

```
function render(filePath, options, callback){

  function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  }

  let views = require(filePath);
  let name = filePath.slice(filePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, -4);
  let componentName = capitalizeFirstLetter(name);
  let Component = views[componentName];
  // current problem is believed to be an import issue. I don't know for sure,
  // but the data seems to be mutated and not in a React form.
  let markup = renderToString(<Component model={options} />)
  return callback(null, markup);
}

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine("jsx", render);
app.set('view engine', 'jsx');
```

My views are written in JSX and stored in the views folder. I am trying to compile them into raw html and css and javascript, and I think this is the way to do it.

```
This is my index route, if it matters.

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is an example of one of my views. This one is the index view.

```
import React from "react";

import Layout from "./layout.jsx";

class Index extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>
        {this.props.model.title}
      </h1>
      <p>
        Welcome to <strong>{this.props.model.title}</strong>
      </p>
    </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export { Index };
```

Here is the error output:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `Index`.
undefined
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `Error`.
undefined
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `Error`.
GET / 500 472.717 ms - 1527
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `Error`.
    at invariant (/Users/Tim/dev/express/myPage2/node_modules/react/node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:38:15)
    at [object Object].instantiateReactComponent [as _instantiateReactComponent] (/Users/Tim/dev/express/myPage2/node_modules/react/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js:85:134)
    at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performInitialMount (/Users/Tim/dev/express/myPage2/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:355:36)
    at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (/Users/Tim/dev/express/myPage2/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:244:21)
    at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (/Users/Tim/dev/express/myPage2/node_modules/react/lib/ReactReconciler.js:46:35)
    at /Users/Tim/dev/express/myPage2/node_modules/react/lib/ReactServerRendering.js:43:36
    at ReactServerRenderingTransaction.Mixin.perform (/Users/Tim/dev/express/myPage2/node_modules/react/lib/Transaction.js:136:20)
    at renderToStringImpl (/Users/Tim/dev/express/myPage2/node_modules/react/lib/ReactServerRendering.js:38:24)
    at renderToString (/Users/Tim/dev/express/myPage2/node_modules/react/lib/ReactServerRendering.js:68:10)
    at View.render (app.js:30:15)
```

I am really trying hard to learn node. I would love any helpful feedback and I am hoping to fix this problem! Thanks for the advice guys! I am pretty decent at React for client side code, but it is kicking my butt on the server. Lol!

Comment: Can you show where and how you did you import the `Index` component ?

Comment: Actually, it is already in there. I require in the views variable with the filePath, and then access each module by name.  Though there is only one for each file, I just ended up doing it this way, because export default was causing trouble. If you look at the variable Component, you can see the end class being imported and follow it up the chain, if you want to figure out how I got there.

Comment: As far as the index component specifically, that is passed through the express middleware by using res.render. It comes in as the filePath on the other side, which is how I accessed and imported it into my view engine in my app.js file.

Comment: If anyone knows, I'm still looking for responses!

Comment: export { Index } change to export default Index

Comment: I think that fixed it. I'll work on it a bit longer to make sure it does, but put your comment in an answer, so I can vote it as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

changed `export { Classname };` to `export default Classname;`
as per Gu mingfeng's suggestion. Also, imported the npm package express-react-views and used that to power my view engine. Still not sure, if this was the best fix and I'll probably look to improve on it, but it works!